# Meaning of "bother" used as a single-word sentence

Tags: word-usage

I know the verb *bother* as in "I didn't bother testing" or the noun *bother* as in "it's no bother", but this is the first time I encounter this word as a kind of interjection or single-word sentence, [written by a native](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48287#c2):

> Note that in casual testing this 'worked', because backspace deletes the pawn and  together. Bother.

What is the meaning of "Bother."? What nuance does it add to the paragraph, which would be missed if it had not been added?

I can't find this usage on [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bother).

The context is the following: He is the guy who is managing bugs, so this bug might *bother* him, or maybe he now regrets that he did not *bother* writing a more complete test.

Comment: I think it's [definition 8 in Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bother): (mainly British) an exclamation of slight annoyance

Comment: If you can't find it on Wiktionary, then use a real dictionary: [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bother) or [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bother). Wiktionary is not the best place to look for usage information or definitions. It has **some** value, but not enough to satisfy me.

Comment: @snailboat As popularized in the U.S. by Winnie the Pooh! ;)

Comment: Wikitionary has the interjection use: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bother#Interjection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

snailboat has found the answer:

http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bother

> exclamation (mainly British) an exclamation of slight annoyance

Comment: "Bother", said Pooh. "There's an infinite number of monkeys at the door who want to sue A.A. Milne for plagiarism".

Comment: Pooh is the only place I've ever heard that expression.